# How to animate an UI without freeze when mouse is not over window?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, freeze

I'm building a game with some shapes that have to rotate, the problem is that, when the mouse go outside from the window it stops animate, and continue in background because when the mouse come again in the window it continues at the good moment

I also tried using `Timer` and `TimerTask` but same problem

I've build a *wonderful minimal and complete example* that explains that :

```
public class Tests extends Application {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    launch(args);    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(); 
        pane.setPrefSize(300, 300);
        Arc arc = new Arc(150, 150, 50, 50, 0, 190.0);
        arc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("#f32f32"));
        Label label = new Label();
        pane.setCenter(arc);
        pane.setTop(label);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> label.setText("Start"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < 360 * 5; i++) {
                        arc.setRotate(i);
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    }
                    Platform.runLater(() -> label.setText("Stop"));
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };    
        new Thread(task).start();
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> { Platform.exit(); System.exit(0); });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't update the UI from a background thread. Use a `Timeline`.

Comment: Or a binding in combination with the `Task.progress` property+`Task.updateProgress`.

Comment: @fabian and rotateProperty so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't expecting to answer my question, but because I found a solution (thank to [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d)'s comment) using `Timeline`, here it is :

```
// Instead of all the Task, only : 
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(arc.rotateProperty(), 1800);
final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), kv);
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
timeline.play();
timeline.setOnFinished(e -> label.setText("Stop"));
```

Comment: @fabian for sure here no need of multiple Timeline, but I need to rotate fast at start and then more and more slowly until it stops quietly, I have to find kind of math function to increase waiting time

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a  Platform.runLater for the rotation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 360 * 5; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    Platform.runLater(() -> arc.setRotate(j));
    Thread.sleep(5)
}
```